# tmux: combining xterm title & tmux provided title

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a `trap` on `DEBUG` signal in bash, to update title in Xterm

```
__title() {
    COMMAND="$BASH_COMMAND"
    case "$COMMAND" in
        history* | autojump*)
            COMMAND=""
            ;;
    esac
    if [ "$COMMAND" ]; then
        echo -ne "\e]0;${COMMAND}\007"
    else
        echo -ne "\e]0; ... \007"
}

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
    case "$TERM" in xterm* | rxvt*)
        trap '__title' DEBUG
        ;;
    esac
fi
```

Is there a way to capture this title in tmux and use it inside pane and window title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to combine `bash` title and `tmux` title

`tmux.conf`:

```
          set-option        -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
          set-option        -g set-titles on
          set-option        -g set-titles-string "#T / #S / #I #F #W"
          set-window-option -g pane-border-status top
          set-window-option -g pane-border-format '#T'
          set -as terminal-overrides ',tmux*:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007'
          set -as terminal-overrides ',screen*:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007'
```

`.bashrc`

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
    case "$TERM" in
        xterm* | rxvt* | tmux* | screen*)
            trap '__title' DEBUG
            ;;
    esac
fi
```